# How to get item name when an item is clicked in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I'm using library to get clicked item of recyclerView, item click is working fine, but when I try to get data i.e. models.get(position).getName(); it is returning a null.

Model is a ArrayList Class including getter and setter method.

```
 RecycleClick.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() 
{
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int 
         position, View v) 
{

   try 
{

    String category=models.get(position).getCategory();

   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),category,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"exception "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Adapter Class:

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context c;
ArrayList<ModelHome> models;
public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ModelHome> models) {
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_screen_row,null);
    return new MyHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, int i)
{

    myHolder.category.setText(models.get(i).category);
    try
    {
        Picasso.get().load(models.get(i).image).into(myHolder.Image);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.loading).into(myHolder.Image);

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}
```

}

Holder Class:

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

```
TextView category;
ImageView Image;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.category=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_title_home);
    this.Image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.firebaseImage_home);
     }
```

}

Model Class:

public class ModelHome {
    String category,image;

```
public ModelHome(String category, String image) {
    this.category = category;
    this.image = image;
}

public ModelHome() {
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

When i click an item and try to fetch corresponding text like :
String category=models.get(position).getCategory();
it is returning null.
i am using try{} catch block

Comment: I think your ArrayList is empty and there is no data on that position so that's why its return null

Comment: Kindly post your Adapter class and Activity class

Comment: what exactly is null there? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Post Adapter class so we can help you and model class.

Comment: Question updated, Please check adapter and holder class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set any data in the RecyclerView Adapter? Please first of all check that.

Comment: i am fetching data from firebase and inserting into Model classs ( ArrayList )

Comment: You have to add the click listener in the Adapter class and If you want to get data from Adapter,you have to use callback.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by eliminating the local ArrayList object , 
use the ModelHome object Globally and the issue will be resolved.